# Basic .NET mapping components?

Tags: open-source-gis, .net, comparison

Which .NET mapping components are currently available? Focus is on desktop use and fairly basic mapping of SHP files (thematics etc.), not the more advanced GIS functionality (reprojections, clipping, point-in-polygon etc). Royalty free distribution is needed.

I am aware of TatukGIS, AspMap, Map Suite and MapXtreme. I believe ESRI has nothing to offer in this area any longer, now that mapobjects is gone.

Other options?
Any stable open source offerings available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/ that has just released 1.0.

From what I can remember this pulls together a number of other components such as Proj4 library and Topology suite.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MapWinGIS](http://mapwingis.codeplex.com/).

> MapWinGIS.ocx is a FREE and OPEN SOURCE C++ based geographic
>   information system programming ActiveX Control and application
>   programmer interface (API) that can be added to a Windows Form in
>   Visual Basic, C#, Delphi, or other languages that support ActiveX,
>   providing your app with a map.

Here's a screenshot of a sample application.

[image]

It's licensed under the [MPL 1.1 license](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/1.1/) so you can use it freely in your commercial and non-commercial applications.

Comment: Dotspatial is native .NET and probably not very stable (early version 1), while mapwingis has it the other way around. Thanks for both suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful component are GMap.Net ( https://greatmaps.codeplex.com ). I used them four years ago for a first application and now I'm able to change and extend my application without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I will put out another option.  [ThinkGeo](http://www.thinkgeo.com) is the option my company chose.  They support your basic mapping operations as well as support for online basemaps from places like Google.  They are royalty free although you do pay a developer license fee.

It is an option.  We are mostly satisfied with them.  There are quirks to their software, just like any other.